# Best practice for pushing a viewController in UINavigationController stack

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

Sorry if this question was asked prior.

I wanted to know how do we handle navigationController stack like am looking for best practices

for now what i am doing is I check if a viewcontroller is already present and then in the navigation stack and then i pop it back by doing something like this

```
bool flag = NO;
    for(LoginViewController *vc in self.navigationController.viewControllers)
    {
        if ([vc isKindOfClass:[LoginViewController class]]) {
            flag = YES;
        }
    }

    if (flag!=YES ){
        LoginViewController *objVC = [[LoginViewController alloc]init];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:objVC animated:YES];
        objVC = nil;
    }else
    {
        [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }
```

Do i really need to check if any viewcontroller is already present in the navigation stack prior pushing it or does the navigation controller takes care of it and at sometime removes the viewcontroller which are not in use. Is there a better way to do this or am i already doing the right thing

In short how we can stop a viewcontroller from being pushed into the navigation stack twice.

Comment: [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES]; will go to the previous controller where you come from so you don't need to check ... any conditions for this.

Comment: Yes that is true but what should be the ideal case should we apply that check or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`popViewControllerAnimated` will always pop the top most VC on the stack. It operates in LIFO fashion.

`LoginViewController` may not necessarily be the top most element on the stack hence in order to remove it you have to modify code this way.

```
LoginViewController *loginVC = nil;
NSUInteger index = [self.navigationController.viewControllers indexOfObjectPassingTest:^BOOL (id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    return [obj isKindOfClass:[LoginViewController class]];
}];

if (index != NSNotFound) {
    //Found VC on stack

    //Get LoginViewController instance
    loginVC = [myArray objectAtIndex:index];
    NSMutableArray *viewControllers = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:self.navigationController.viewControllers];
    //Remove LoginViewController obj from stack
    [viewControllers removeObjectIdenticalTo:loginVC];
    //Reassign new array which does not contain LoginViewController
    navigationController.viewControllers = viewControllers;
}
else {
    //VC not found on stack
    LoginViewController *objVC = [[LoginViewController alloc]init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:objVC animated:YES];
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Ok my question is that if i am at thirdVC and from thirdVC i come back to secondVC then if i use push then my stack trace of navigation will be
secondVC, thirdVC, secondVC,thirdVC so in that case do i use the above code to check things

Comment: What do you mean by come back?

Comment: One quick question : How can we stop a view controller from being pushed twice in the navigation stack

Comment: @user2538944 A correctly designed UI flow will not lead to such problems. However, the code above will work in that case as well. Check and remove the VC before pushing it.